# Why does Lagrange Multiplier fail to find Min/Max points?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

I am trying to do ques. 21 from stewart calculus. The question is given below.

[image: Ques. 21]

**a)**

$\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g $

$\nabla g = (4x^3 - 3x^2) \hat i + (2y) \hat j$

$\nabla f = (1) \hat i $

System of Equations to find $(x,y)$ & $\lambda$

$1 = \lambda  (4x^3 - 3x^2) $ --- **eqn. 1**

$0 = \lambda  (2y) $ --- **eqn. 2**

$0 = y^2 + x^4 - x^3 $ --- **eqn. 3**

$\lambda$ cannot be zero because of equation 1 even though equation 2 suggests.

therefore $y = 0$.

from eqn. 3 we can find $x$ for $y = 0$

$x = 0$ or $1$

If $x = 0$ equation 1 is Not satisfied. Therefore $x = 1$

For $x = 1$, $\lambda = 1$ from equation 1.

Finally, $x = 1,$ $y = 0$ and $\lambda = 1$ These should give the minimum/maximum point right?

I only have one point so how do I know if it is a max or min value? should I use the 2nd derivative test using hessian?

**b)** How to show minimum is at (0,0)?
I can easily show $\nabla f(0,0)$ $!= \lambda \nabla g(0,0) $ from above.

Please explain this first. I will try to do C by myself.

**c)**

Thanks.

Comment: to show that the minimum is attained at $(0,0)$, note that if $(x,y)$ satisfy $y^2+x^4-x^3 = 0$, then $0\leq y^2 = x^3-x^4$ and thus $x^4\leq x^3$ which is only possible if $x\geq 0$. It follows that $f(x,y)\geq 0$ on the piriform. Since $f(0,0)=0$, $(0,0)$ must be a minimum.

Comment: Please see here: https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/nunemacher01010325718.pdf

Comment: @Surb For part **a)** is the point (1,0) for $\lambda = 1$ a stationary point (maximum)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point of part (b) is to get an answer **not** using Lagrange multipliers.

$x^3-x^4=x^3(1-x)$ is equal to $y^2$ and so is non-negative. Therefore $0\le x\le1$ and the minimum is at $(0,0)$.

This also answers you query re. part (a). The point $(1,0)$ gives a maximum.